# Concatenate device readings in JSON object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, date

I have devices in the field that send readings in the format of sessions to a database. These sessions have a start time, an end time and a session time value (indicating how long the session was). When I call the database (MySQL), it sends me back each row with the start, end and duration times for each session for the device, in a defined month that I request (for example I can send it December 2018 for all sessions in that month). This is what the database send back to me:

```
DeviceUID: xxx-xxx-xxx
Start Date: 2018-12-10T17:12:31.000Z
End Date: 2018-12-10T21:32:12.000Z <- I convert this to YY:MM:DD HH:mm:ss
Duration: 16237312                 <- This is a value in seconds
```

What I want to do, is to create a JSON object that has an entry for each day of the month, and a value for the total duration of sessions on that day. Note that each day should have ONLY ONE entry, that sums all the duration for that day. See below:

```
{
  "2018-12-01": "02:12:54",   <-- duration in HH:mm:ss
  "2018-12-02": "01:43:52",
  ...
}
```

The code I currently have can do a for each loop through the rows I receive from the MySQL database, but I'm not sure how to approach the summation of durations per day and how to get it into a JSON properly. Could you please help me out?

**NOTE**: I take the day as the end date only. Thus, if a session started on 2018-12-01 and ended on 2018-12-02, I will add the session's duration to 2018-12-02's value only.

Comment: The expected output is captured in the code window above. That is the JSON structure.

Comment: Can you please include your sample date for the month? and add expected output.

Comment: We would need the output object of MySQL. Operations with time can easily done with https://momentjs.com

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your code base looks like, but these are the steps that you need to take:

- Name the object *data*, and name the first key in the object *date*.
- Name a second field called *duration*.
- Set the value of date to the date that the user has requested.
- In your for each that goes through each device, calculate the difference between your end time and start time.

I tried my best to understand your question, and from what I understand, you want the total time of all devices while in a session.

So:

- Initialize *duration* by setting it to 0.
- Then, in the for each, add the difference between your end time and start time to *duration*.
- Return the object to the user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I've already got the worked out duration in seconds, I just need to convert it to HH:mm:ss. The real issue for me is how I go through the for each and add multiple durations that occur on the same day to a single entry / sum for that day, and display it as a single entry.

Comment: You're going through a database, right? The object is seperate, so you build it from scratch outside the for each. Inside the for each, you get your sessions duration from the db data, and add it to the object that was defined outside of the for each.

Then, after the for each, you return the object.